# Persisting a context menu after screen rotation

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have an activity that on it's onCreate method it does:

> registerForContextMenu(theView);

and in onCreateContextMenu:

```
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
menu.add(blablabla);
```

This works great, but the problem is that the context menu disappears when the screen rotates.
How to fix this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution:

The contextMenu disappeared because by default when rotating android calls destroy() and then onCreate() **but** :

If you don't want Android to go through the normal activity destroy-and-recreate process; instead, you want to handle recreating the views yourself, you can use the android:configChanges attributes on the  element in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SmsPopupActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:taskAffinity="net.everythingandroid.smspopup.popup">
</activity>
```

This way my contextMenu is not closed when my phone rotates, because onCreate() method is not called.

See also:

- [Developing Orientation-Aware Android Applications](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/1763/page/5)
- [activity-restart-on-rotation-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Android developers blog:

> The Activity class has a special method called onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). This 
>   method can be used to pass an
>   arbitrary object your future self and
>   Android is smart enough to call this
>   method only when needed. [...]
>   The implementation can be summarized
>   like so:

```
@Override public Object
onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
final LoadedPhoto[] list = new LoadedPhoto[numberOfPhotos];
keepPhotos(list);
return list; }
```

> In the new activity, in onCreate(),
>   all you have to do to get your object
>   back is to call
>   getLastNonConfigurationInstance(). In
>   Photostream, this method is invoked
>   and if the returned value is not null,
>   the grid is loaded with the list of
>   photos from the previous activity:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html?utm_source=eddie

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but from what I know you cant persist it, however (this is the part where i may be wrong in) you could open the menu dynamically after you rotate. Giving the illusion of persistence.

Comment: I tried that.There is a method called openContextMenu(view) but couldn't make it work :(

Comment: This may be obvious, but just for sanity, are you calling openContextMenu only after calling registerForContextMenu on the view?

Comment: yes. Tried to call it on onCreate and onResume and in boths it fails :(

Comment: How about simulating the menu key being pressed?

Comment: @Faisal Abid: How would you do that. Remember that it isn't a common menu, it's a contextMenu that shows up when you do a long press.

Comment: Ahh my apologizes, I thought this was the common menu. Well in that case, it changes everything. Hmm let me do some googling and test this with my app to see what i can find