# Android - Text Field goes to white screen when turned sideways

Tags: android, orientation

For my app, when I enter text into the text field and then turn the screen sideways, the entire view turns white. Here are some images to show it:

9:16 aspect ratio, vertical:

[image]

16:9 aspect ratio, horizontal:

[image]

Is this an easy fix or is there serious time commitment in order to make this word properly for landscape orientation as well?

Comment: This isn't the textview going fullscreen. Its how the OS handles the keyboard in landscape.

Comment: Do you have problem with losing text entered into it, or just with the look of the textview horizontally?

Comment: @EMarci15 Just the look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` in the EditText XML properties

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the way the keyboard works when you input text in landscape. I don't think there's any other way to change or get rid of the white background, but the TextView should still work the same.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape), you can try to override the UI full screen editing method with:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I just get an error when I put that. It tells me to remove the `@Override` statement and then when I do, it tell me that the method needs to `return` something or be cast as `void`, neither of which work.

Answer (score 0):

When a screen rotation takes place, the current activity is destroyed and recreated.  This may be the cause of your issue.

Maybe this SO post will help...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673374/1246574

Also here's the documentation that gives details about how to handle activity life cycle, including when an activity is destroyed due to screen rotation...

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

In Themes.xml
create a separate style

```
<style name="Theme.AppName.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:theme"> @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

And **AndroidManifest**

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppName.NoActionBar"
```